# Setting Workspaces in Gnome without activating gnome panel (and workspaces applet)

Tags: gnome-panel, applet, workspaces

I'm using Avant Window Navigator and don't have any gnome-panel. But, I wanna resize my workspaces from 4x1 to 2x2. But in the help and other documentation, to do this, I must right click in Workspaces applet in gnome panel. Can I do this without activating gnome panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure your workspaces through CompizConfig Settings Manager (ccsm)

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

It's placed in System > Preferences > CompizConfig Settings Manager.

You will find the setting under General Options>Desktop Size.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if indicator-workspaces will is what you are looking for you need to install i from a personal ppa.

in terminal type

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:geod/ppa-geod`

then

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install indicator-workspaces`

it will be in your accessories menu.

Hope this helps